# Suddenly "The syntax of the command is incorrect" in batch SET line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, batch-file

I'm running the current version of Windows 10 (updated yesterday) and for unknown reasons, I am not able to start [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) anymore, with Windows (the PowerShell as well as the Command Prompt) giving me "The syntax of the command is incorrect" - without me having changed anything in maven. I also downloaded the most recent version, same problem.

Might have to do with the recent windows update (September 14, 2021—KB5005565 (OS Builds 19041.1237, 19042.1237, and 19043.1237), not sure there, but it worked for years without problems and the problem started on the same day the update appeared on my system (albeit before I actually updated and restarted).

The script looks like this...

```
@REM Begin all REM lines with '@' in case MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO is 'on'
@echo off
@REM enable echoing my setting MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO to 'on'
@if "%MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO%"=="on" echo %MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO%

@REM Execute a user defined script before this one
if not "%MAVEN_SKIP_RC%"=="" goto skipRcPre
@REM check for pre script, once with legacy .bat ending and once with .cmd ending
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat" %*
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd" %*
:skipRcPre

@setlocal

set ERROR_CODE=0

@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto OkJHome
for %%i in (java.exe) do set "JAVACMD=%%~$PATH:i"
goto checkJCmd

:OkJHome
set "JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

:checkJCmd
if exist "%JAVACMD%" goto chkMHome
```

I've tried to switch to `@echo=on` for some output where this might fail, but it really doesn't help me much. The output, when the script is run from it's folder (to avoid any path problems) seems to indicate that the SET ... command is the problem. When run (from the same folder) with `@echo=on`, the script produces this output:

```
C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>.\mvn

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPre

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>if exist "C:\Users\Flo\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\Flo\mavenrc_pre.bat"

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>if exist "C:\Users\Flo\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "C:\Users\Flo\mavenrc_pre.cmd"

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>set ERROR_CODE=0 

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10""=="" goto OkJHome

C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>
```

Strangely, calling `set ERROR_CODE=0` manually in the console doesn't display any error.

Updates recently:

- September 14, 2021—KB5005565 (OS Builds 19041.1237, 19042.1237, and 19043.1237)
- KB4023057
- August 10, 2021—KB5005033 (OS Builds 19041.1165, 19042.1165, and 19043.1165)
  ...now we are back more than 1 month and it worked until the day before yesterday.

Comment: Why does every line of your code have `C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>`?  You suspect a Windows Update is the problem but don't mention which update exactly you are suspicious of? Please [edit] your question to use proper formatting and to include the necessary information to answer your question. [It's probably a PATH variable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867284/command-prompt-returns-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect-when-running-an).  I wouldn't expect `set ERROR_CODE=0` by itself to generate any output, so typing it manually, is not a valid test.

Comment: Because that's the output of the script when run directly from it's folder with `echo=on`, to prevent any path problems. I've added the part of the script that seems to make the problems and the windows update - but I'm unsure there, since the problem started before half a day before I got around actually click "Update & Shutdown" - just the indicator that the update was available was there all the time.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting conditional statements as the output of a script.  How you are running the script is likely the problem. What updates have been recently installed are listed in `View update history` within Settings -> Windows Update.  I glazed over the fact you had `echo=on` which would explain why conditional statements are being printed. Have you checked the PATH variable?

Comment: Well, with `@echo=on`, every command is printed line by line, so that's that why I get the commands there. To only real output from the script itself is "The syntax of the command is incorrect." after the SET command.
Also added the history.

Comment: A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311224/axis2-with-maven).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The line showing the error is actually this one, not the one directly before the output, for whatever reason:

```
C:\[..]\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10""=="" goto OkJHome
```

There are two double quotation marks at the end of the path, not just one. This is very likely the result of a wrong attempt to SET JAVA_HOME to something ending, but not starting with double quotation marks, obviously my fault.

Seems like the update was purely coincidentally in the same time period, a nice wrong hering reality held in front of my eyes, tsk.